# Negative String do decimal nsnumber

Tags: ios, string, swift, double, nsnumber

Im trying to convert a String to a decimal Double or NSNumber.

Heres my string :

```
"-2000" or "2000"
```

which should become :

```
-20.00 or 20.00
```

already tried :

```
print("NSNumber \(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(amount)!.decimalValue)")
print("Double \(Double(amount))")
```

but when its negative return nil, or when its positive returns only one number after the comma.

Comment: `print((Double("-2000") ?? 0) / 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Double(("-2000" as NSString).doubleValue / 100)
```

I would create a simple extension (String+decimalPrice.swift) for that

```
extension String {
    var decimalPrice: Double {
        return (self as NSString).doubleValue / 100
    }
}

let price = "-999".decimalPrice
print(price) # -> -9.99
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var amount = "-2000"  // String
var doubleNumber = Double(amount / 100)! // Double
var stringWithFormat = NSString(format: "formatted number %.2f", doubleNumber) // to get String with your format
```

When variable is Double. -20.0 and -20.00 are same value.
Only if variable is String "-20.0" and "-20.00" are different

Comment: But that gives me "-2000.00", thats not what im looking for, i need "-20.00"

Comment: var doubleNumber = Double(amount / 100)!

Comment: `Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'`

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to convert a String into a NSNumber and then print it with 2 numbers after the comma

```
let value = "-2000"
let f = NSNumberFormatter()
f.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle      
let n = f.numberFromString(value)!
NSLog("%.2f", n.floatValue)
```